# Dropping Label into empty vertical StackView automatically shrinks the stack

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new to `XCode` and all things iPhone and I noticed something which I assume is the correct behaviour but it seems a bit strange to me to adapt to. For reference:

```
XCode version 11.3
Storyboard device view: iPhone 11
```

When I create a new project and drop `VerticalStackView` into the main Storyboard view in the centre of it its size is automatically set to some reasonably sized rectangle container which I can freely and easily change by dragging the corners of it as I please:

[image]

Now, when I then drop a label into the the `StackView` at first everything seems ok

[image]

However an instant later, the `StackView` size automatically shrinks to the size of the just dropped in label which I can not change.

[image]

Inspecting the size of the StackView in its Size Inspector I can see the Width and Height to be set to fixed values (that reflect the fixed values of the label).

Anyone knows what is causing this automatic behaviour and how can I change it? I'm assuming this is the correct behaviour in a sense that `StackView` automatically changes its size to the size defined by the object dropped into it, however I'd like to do that later on once I'm happy with some basic look and I've added auto layout constraint rather than `XCode` doing some automatic for me. Is there any way I can modify this behaviour?

Comment: No you can't, this is the automatic behaviour of StackView. A StackView calculates its height from subviews. You can give height Constraint to label to change the size. Other thing is subclassing StackView and overriding properties but it's not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a somewhat odd approach. You want to add subviews to a `UIStackView` --- but you don't want the stack view to apply any layout attributes until you're *"happy with some basic look"* ... however, as soon as you then apply constraints, that look will change. Either the stack view will change size, or the subview will change size.

You *could* do this:

- place your stack view where you want it
- give it width and height and position constraints
- add your subviews

This will prevent the stack view from changing size. As you add subviews, perhaps you decide the stack view needs to be taller... so edit the height constraint.

or...

- place your stack view where you want it
- In **Size Inspector**, change **Layout** from `Automatic` to `Translates Mask Into Constraints`

This will also prevent the stack view from changing size / position.

In both cases, though, the stack view's ***arranged subviews*** will continue to be affected by the stack view's layout properties. And, it seems like you will have much more difficulty switching to auto-layout and applying the correct constraints.